# Arduino Uno unable to detect serial port on MAC os Mojave 10.14.2

Tags: arduino-uno, mac-os

Ive upgraded to Mojave.  I've never used Arduino before.  I was given Arduino Uno.
Arduino Uno does not find any serial ports... can't load Blink example (the first step)

In blind frustration, I tried the three ports available... None of work.

I've loaded the 
CH34x_Install_V1.4.pkg
to no avail.

How do I get a serial port package that will enable serial ports in general (and more importantly for arduino)

thx,
Bruce
On a related Note: the list of things that Mojave broke is long!  To solve many problems, re-install xcode FIRST!!! and read articles on apache, there is a "new and improve" apache server embedded in mojave.

Comment: you have it mixed up .... the Arduino Uno does not detect a serial port ..... the MAC detects the Arduino Uno as a USB serial port which can then be selected in the Arduino IDE

Comment: OK.  What can I do to get the serial port to show up in the IDE?  Currently the IDE sees /dev/cs.Bluetooth-Incoming-Port, /dev/cu.BrucesiPhone-WirelessiAP and /dev/cu.SSDC

Comment: I have this problem too ... plug the arduino into a USB port and nothing happens. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlejsgxOxrU)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a genuino or genuine Arduino, the most common cause of this is using a USB *power only* cable to connect rather than a data cable. (You only need the CH34x_Install_V1.4.pkg if you are running an Arduino clone based on that chipset)

If I ran the world, the USB standard would include some way to distinguish whether it's power only or power and data without having to [test it with a multimeter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/140229/171525). I know, I know, that's crazy talk.